# Почему не видит conemu gitbash?

Tags: git, conemu

Привет. Установил Git bash. Установил Conemu. В разделе tasks Conemu не видит git bash. Как тогда добавить свой task вручную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нажимаете "+" в левом нижнем углу и настраиваете как вам надо.

И между прочим, git bash есть из коробки, по крайней мере я его не настраивал и он есть у меня.

[image: Настройки conemu]

Answer (score 2):

ConEmu не должен ничего "видеть". Tasks настраиваются пользователем. Просто некоторые часто используемые уже настроены разработчиком. Возможно, при обновлении ConEmu и у вас этот task появится, а может и нет. Вы можете сами добавить новый task с такими параметрами:

- Name - `Bash::git bash` (оно может быть любым, на ваше усмотрение)
- Task parameters - остается пустым
- Commands - `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` (если путь к Git другой - укажите ваш)

Все. Это позволит вам запускать Git Bash из ConEmu, как и другие таски.

Дополнительно, может быть удобно добавить запуск Git Bash в ConEmu в контекстное меню проводника. Для этого нужно пойти в `Integration`, раздел `ConEmu Here`:

- Menu item - `Git Bash (ConEmu) here`
- Command - `/single -run {Git Bash}` (В фигурных скобках имя таска, которое было введено на предыдущем шаге)

  - Icon file - `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico`
  - Нажать кнопку `Register`